# Java Server Trouble: can't change from "localhost"

Tags: java, sockets, java-7, serversocket

My problem is that I have a server that works (for the most part) it gets data from my game and then sends back to it the locations of other players on the screen. On the Server side terminal window, it displays all the player locations and player numbers. Problem is that no one else can join to test because the server is local host and I can't fix it. How do I set the server to run off another IP other than "localhost"?

In the code I have this to make a ServerSocket:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(63400);
```

That makes it run from local host, how would I make it run from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, being my ip address?

Comment: Make sure it's bound to something other than the loop back adapter, and then make sure that your router (assuming you have one) is setup to forward ports properly.

Comment: Ok i have tried this. But this does not explain what the external user should be putting in for the ip to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run ServerSocket on your local machine ie localhost. As the comment on your question alludes to, you need to make sure that your router and your firewall are set up to forward requests to your machine.

Comment: ok let me try that out. thank you for being so quick about it.